# bash for loop, use input filename in the output filename

Tags: bash

I want to use my input filename (baseline.YYYYMM.tar) in my output filename (baseline.YYYYMM.var1.tar). I can process the input files but don't know how to pass the output filename I need to my cdo application:

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix="basename"
fndate=$(ls | grep tar|cut -c 10-15)
var="var1"
extension=".tar"
outputfile=$prefix $fndate $var $extension
for f in $(find . -name "*.tar" -print) ; do
cdo selname,var1 $f $outputfile
done
```

thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clearer what the actual problem is and how we can help you?

Comment: Don't parse `ls` and definitely not randomly on the output of an entire directory. If you have a file you want the info for use `stat` on that file specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I get what you're trying to do but if I'm right, you should be able to use something like this to get your output file name from the input:

```
var=var1
for f in *.tar; do
    output=$(awk -v s="$var" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{print $1, $2, s, $3}' <<<"$f")
    # use "$output" however you want, e.g.
    echo "$output"
done
```

This uses awk to split up the input file name `$f` and insert the shell variable `$var` in the middle. `<<<"$f"` is bash syntax, equivalent to `echo "$f" |` at the start of the command.

Answer (score 1):

(I agree with remarks about parsing ls.)
Did you forget dots?

```
 outputfile=$prefix $fndate $var $extension
```

should be

```
outputfile=${prefix}.${fndate}.${var}${extension}
```

Comment: Thx Walter. Parsing was meant as a placeholder for a safer way to provide input.